# PHP + cURL - Scraping data from a website with user profile using REACT

Tags: php, reactjs, web-scraping

Id like to scrap data from a div on codecademy I have the login sorted out but the data is loaded via react.js so I cant use a simple_html_dom to get the info I need.

Answer (score 2):

It probably won't be that easy. Pages rendered using React, or any other javascript intensive framework, only load the majority of the content through javascript. This means that initially only a stub site gets loaded into the DOM. Then javascript kicks in and adds new nodes to the DOM.
If you want to scrape content from such websites you need to simulate a browser. You could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this. It is a headless browser implementation in javascript. I'm not aware of any headless browsers for PHP.